# regular expression calculation

Tags: regex

Does anyone know the regular expressions (or other type of quick commands)  to calculate `47380539-47366525` from this string?

```
1:47366525-47380539
```

Stuck on this for a script.

Comment: What environment/os are you in?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are doing some shell scripting, here are some Perl examples.

To match `47366525-47380539` in `1:47366525-47380539`:

```
echo 1:47366525-47380539 | perl -nE '/:([\d-]+)/ && say $1'
```

If you want to calculate the result of the mathematical expression:

```
echo 1:47366525-47380539 | perl -nE '/:([\d-]+)/ && say eval $1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to extract the relevant part (regex cannot do math).

```
\d+:(\d+-\d+)
```

This regex will match a string in the format `digits:digits-digits` You can extract the first captured group to get the required part.

Comment: Probably better to use `\d+:(\d+)-(\d+)` so you get two capture groups, which can be directly converted to integers.